# How do i delete my last character from output (%)?

Tags: java, signals, ssid

I am trying to get signal strength from SSID. 
My output is: ssid name + signal
Example: GIGABYTE    92%
But i want to output only: GYGABYTE 92

I want to know how can i remove last character from my output (%).

Please help me to solve it.

This is my code:

```
  ArrayList<String>ssids=new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String>signals=new ArrayList<String>();
     ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
             "cmd.exe", "/c", "netsh wlan show all");
     builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
     Process p = null;
    try {
        p = builder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     String line;
     while (true) {
         try {
            line = r.readLine();

         if (line.contains("SSID")||line.contains("Signal")){
             if(!line.contains("BSSID"))
                 if(line.contains("SSID")&&!line.contains("name")&&!line.contains("SSIDs"))
                 {
                     line=line.substring(8);
                     ssids.add(line);

                 }
                 if(line.contains("Signal"))
                 {
                     line=line.substring(30);
                     signals.add(line);

                 }

                 if(signals.size()==7)
                 {
                     break;
                 }

         }
         } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

     }
     for (int i=1;i<ssids.size();i++)
     { 

         System.out.println(ssids.get(i)+"    "+signals.get(i));

     }

}
```

}

Comment: You have several options. Simplest of them would be to use `String#substring()`

Comment: Another way is to use String#replaceAll method.

Comment: String,substring(0, String.length() - 2)

Comment: @MateuszStefaniak - Yes, but that would probably be an overkill :)

Comment: String.replaceAll("%","");

Comment: @MateuszStefaniak Then what if the network name contains a % character? `replaceAll` is not suitable here.

Comment: @Sonor Your comment with `substring` has 2 issues. Can you find them?

Comment: when my signal ouputs have the character %

Comment: @Tom String object is null, String object has a size <= 2, String not contains the '%' character. We can do somes corner tests and also test if String contains '%' character before do substring

Comment: @Sonor Your `-2` is already wrong, or do you expect another char right after the "%"? And you wrote `String,substring`, instead of `String.substring`, but that typo isn't that important.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a :

```
line = line.substring(0,line.length() - 1);
```

will help you ;)